# How to split AJAX response into two divs

Tags: php, ajax

How I could get AJAX response splitted in two separate divs?

Situation: I have custom post type (case-studies) filter by custom taxonomy(case study category). On page load I query by exact category. But when I filter it by category I want to get AJAX response divided into two parts. First one even posts appears in filtered-post-top div and odd posts appears in filtered-post-bottom div.

Here is what I have achieved so far.

functionts.php file:

```
function filter_ajax() {


  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
          'terms' => $category
      )
    )
  );
  
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if($query->have_posts()) :
      while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'partials/case-studies-archive-post' );
      endwhile;
  endif;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
      die();
  }
```

ajaxRequest.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-item > span').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).data('category');
        console.log(category);
        data = {
            'action': 'filter',
            'category': category
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : wp_ajax.ajax_url,
            data : data,
            type : 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('.filtered-posts').html(result);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
            }
        });
    })

});
```

Maybe someone will have idea how to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to be in separate `<div>` elements or can you get away with styling it into two columns using CSS?

Comment: I would like to have it in two separate divs. Because between them, there is filter with filter items. 
Example: 
<div class="filtered-posts-top">Even Posts</div>
<div class="case-studies-categories">Filter with all filter items</div>
<div class="filtered-posts-bottom">Odd Posts</div>
I can't figure out this with CSS I think...
Here is the same idea what I want to achieve: https://www.rainfall.com/